# divide ExtJS form between two windows

Tags: extjs

I need to make an app that shows a form in a window on one screen and the main window with part of the same form - or is this is'n possible another form - on the other screen. Is this possible with ExtJs ? How ? Has anyone seen an example or perhaps an extension that does such ?

Comment: Do you mean to physical screens or two ExtJS Windows?

Comment: two physical screens but split a form between two ExtJs windows is perhaps the first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 'card' layout inside your form.
In the following example, the user sees three different pages, the first two pages have fields and the last one a button.

Clicking on the button retrieves the values from the fields. It doesn't matter that the fields are in different containers, as long as these containers are 'descendants' of the form.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout:'card',
            activeItem: 0,
            bbar: [{
                text: '&laquo; Previous',
                handler: function(button) {
                    var cardlayout = button.up('form').getLayout();
                    var prev = cardlayout.getPrev();
                    if (prev) {
                        cardlayout.setActiveItem(prev);
                    }
                }
            },{
                text: 'Next &raquo;',
                handler: function(button) {
                    var cardlayout = button.up('form').getLayout();
                    var next = cardlayout.getNext();
                    if (next) {
                        cardlayout.setActiveItem(next);
                    }
                }
            }],
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'First name',
                    name: 'firstName'
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Last name',
                    name: 'lastName'
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Submit',
                    handler: function(button) {
                        var formValues = button.up('form').getValues();
                        alert('Name: ' + formValues.firstName
                              + ' ' + formValues.lastName);
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```